# Groovy HTTPBuilder get last modified datetime

Tags: groovy, http-headers, httpbuilder

I am trying to fetch some files from internet. I want to update my schedule service if the last modified time update. With HTTPBuilder I am unable to find the server response with *last-modified* parameter. Is there any way to get this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the [docs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) `Last-Modified` is a header and should be searched among other headers. What's important is that it's server that decides if `Last-Modified` header will be included in the response. Hence, if the server you connect to doesn't return the header in the response it's impossible to get the value.

Headers can be obtained via `response` object, see below:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1') 

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.GET
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://www.google.com/search' )

http.request(GET,TEXT) { req ->
    response.success = { res ->
        res.headers.each { h ->
            println h
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Opal my server returning this header how to get it. How to get headers?

Comment: @JavaGeek, if you found my answer helpful please accept and upvote it.